Datatable big data around 40k takes too long to filter
I am currently using the latest version of jQuery DataTables.
I have multiple filters and a search bar.
However, when I use any of them, it takes about 30 seconds to display the results. According to Google's performance check, the long task is within the DataTable script.
Sometimes it gets stuck while filtering rows, causing the browser to crash.
The Datatable function that takes too long is _fnFilter which runs couples of time with each filter.
I have tried everything but nothing seems to help.
This issue occurred on Google Chrome but not in Firefox.

"I have tried everything" - if you have tried everything, then there is nothing left for you to try.

If you have not actually tried everything, you can use server-side processing: "There are times when reading data from the DOM is simply too slow or unwieldy, particularly when dealing with many thousands or millions of data rows. To address this DataTables' server-side processing feature provides a method to let all the "heavy lifting" be done by a database engine on the server-side". All pagination, sorting, and filtering is done on the server. You are therefore responsible for providing that server-side logic.

Yeah but the thing is that is working corrctely in my staging env and not in prod which use the same DB
